# Display NAL H.264 UDP Stream (in VLC)

Tags: stream, udp, h.264, drone.io

I am trying to display the video my (PAUL) drone is sending to my over a UDP connection.

Frames look like (hexdump):

```
00  00  01  a1  00  1d  00  03          
90  1a  00  00  a0  8a  dc  0c  
00  00  00  00  03  00  00  00  
d0  02  40  02  00  04  00  00  
90  1a  00  00  19  00 ......
```

Frames always start (trough my observation) with:

```
00  00  01  a
```

Are these NAL units?

I am want to display this in VLC player but don't know how to stream it to the VLC media player.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like a valid h.264 bitstream, but its not. `00 00 01` does look like a start code, But after a start code the first bit MUST be 0. `a` in binary is `1010` hence not valid.